# How to generate child csv file from parent csv file using python script?

Tags: python-2.7

I have one csv files it's like raw report so I want few rows from that which contain specific string in each row.
Parent file:

```
cols: A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I  J   K   L M N O
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
      abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yz aaa bbb X 0 0 ajsjsvdjchbiyu ======kjdkjfk
      abe drf gti jul muo pir stu vwx yz aaa bbb X 0 0 ajsjsvdjchbiyu ======kjdkjfk
      abe drf gti j8l 7uo pir stu vwx yz aaa bbb Y 0 0 ajsjsvdjchbiyu ======kjdkjfk
      abe drf gti j8l 7uo pir stu vwx yz aga btb Y 0 0 ajsjsvdjchbiyu ======kjdkjfk
```

Child file should be:(I need only below rows which contains Y in row L)

```
cols: A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I  J   K   L M N O
      abe drf gti j8l 7uo pir stu vwx yz aaa bbb Y 0 0 ajsjsvdjchbiyu ======kjdkjfk
      abe drf gti j8l 7uo pir stu vwx yz aga btb Y 0 0 ajsjsvdjchbiyu ======kjdkjfk
```

I have written below script to do that:

```
import sys

fs=open("compliance_report.csv",'r')
fe=open("failed_controls_report.csv",'w')

count=0
lDict={}

fe.write("\n")
print  "\nCleaning un-wanted lines from raw report...."

for l in fs:
    if'Y' in l:

        fe.write(l)

    else:
        continue

count=count+1

fs.close()
fe.close()
```

We have text in "0" column so when I use this script I'm getting the result in same row.
but this is working without "0" column

Comment: You should have a look at **Pandas**.

Comment: Use the built-in [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module for manipulation of CSV data. Your code will write any row containing `Y`, no matter in which column.

Comment: [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) is good for simple queries: `awk '$12 == "Y"'  inputfiles` ($12 is the 12 th column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module to actually parse the lines into fields. With the code you have now you're just searching the entire line for any `Y` character which obviously is not what you want.  You can know your code cannot possibly be correct because it never mentions "column L" at all, despite that column being part of the problem statement.

Comment: Can I have the syntax for exact output ?
(and I'm getting error(getting out put file with single row) with last column which is column "0" as this column contains text(with symbols,special chars, spaces etc..))

Comment: In the above script, how can I specify the particular column instead of entire row ?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way would be to use the **Pandas** library. The procedure with pandas would look something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

# Read csv
df = pd.read_csv("pathtocsv")

# Filter column N
df= df[df["N"] > "Y"]

# Write to csv again
df.to_csv("newcsvpath")
```